# filter and unfilter in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

What would be the dplyr analog of performing the following operation in base R?

```
iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length>2] <- iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Length>2] * 10
```

I am trying to use filter but cannot go back to the original data set (without a `join`)

Comment: `mutate` with `ifelse`, e.g. `iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 2, Sepal.Length * 10, Sepal.Length))`

Comment: Been using dplyr for years, haven’t figured this one out yet myself. There’s a dplyr extension library that implements this but that’s clearly not satisfactory.

Comment: @alistaire Do you want to make an answer? You come up with it first. If you want to, I can remove mine.

Comment: Eh, same time; it's fine as-is

Comment: @Sumedh That’s terribly inefficient, isn’t it?

Comment: Yep, just did `microbenchmark`. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `mutate` with `ifelse` to get the same results as comments from @alistaire:

```
iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 2, Sepal.Length * 10, Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: Good answer, yet somehow unsatisfactory. I’m really missing a `mutate_if`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Not really used that function before. Might be a better solution. I am wondering if that is column condition, i.e., predicate for selecting columns.

Comment: That’s the point: the function [doesn’t exist (in dplyr)](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/425) (dplyr 5.0 does introduce a function of that name, but it inexplicably and annoyingly does something different).

Comment: `dplyr` has currently `if_else` function, which is quite like `base::ifelse` but provides stronger typing.

Answer (score 3):

If we are using `data.table`, we can avoid the `ifelse` and make it faster

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(iris)[Sepal.Length > 2, Sepal.Length := Sepal.Length * 10]
```