# Working on a subset of data/specific rows (based on a certain condition) using the pipe operator

Tags: r, magrittr

The following example works using "[". However I would like to know whether there is a more tidyverse-like approach to change the values of specific rows using the %>% operator.

Assume I want change the iris data set but without manipulating the rows where the species is versicolor.

```
library(dplyr)

data("iris")

iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

iris[iris$Species!="versicolor",] <- iris[iris$Species!="versicolor",] %>% 

  mutate(

    Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length * 100,

    Species = paste0(Species, "_o0o0o0o0o0o0")

  )

distinct(iris, Species, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Desired output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width                Species
1          510         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
2            7         3.2          4.7         1.4             versicolor
3          630         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
```

Comment: you could use ifelse(Species!="versicolor", Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length * 100, Seapl.Length) in mutate. But, just my personal taste, i would keep the [] indexing method.

Comment: For @TinglTanglBob's suggestion, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598895/filter-and-unfilter-in-dplyr

Comment: @TinglTanglBob, thanks! I've seen that before but I don't like it so much. In my opinion It makes the code more complicated. I rather hoped there was something like mutate_if. However, that refers to conditions in the columns and not rows.
The ifelse approach gets complicated if I want to do many changes to the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use `if_else` within `mutate`

```r
library(dplyr)

data("iris")

iris1 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species),
         Sepal.Length = if_else(Species != "versicolor", Sepal.Length * 100, Sepal.Length),
         Species2     = if_else(Species != "versicolor", paste0(Species, "_o0o0o0o0o0o0"), Species))

iris1  

#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1          510.0         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 2          490.0         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3          470.0         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 4          460.0         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 5          500.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 6          540.0         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
#> 7          460.0         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> 8          500.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 9          440.0         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 10         490.0         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
#> 11         540.0         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 12         480.0         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 13         480.0         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> 14         430.0         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
#> 15         580.0         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 16         570.0         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 17         540.0         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa
#> 18         510.0         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> 19         570.0         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
#> 20         510.0         3.8          1.5         0.3     setosa
#> 21         540.0         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa
#> 22         510.0         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 23         460.0         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa
#> 24         510.0         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
#> 25         480.0         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa
#> 26         500.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 27         500.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     setosa
#> 28         520.0         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 29         520.0         3.4          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 30         470.0         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 31         480.0         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 32         540.0         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 33         520.0         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
#> 34         550.0         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 35         490.0         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 36         500.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 37         550.0         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 38         490.0         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> 39         440.0         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 40         510.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 41         500.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> 42         450.0         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> 43         440.0         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 44         500.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
#> 45         510.0         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa
#> 46         480.0         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> 47         510.0         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 48         460.0         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 49         530.0         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 50         500.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#> 54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#> 55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#> 56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#> 57           6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
#> 58           4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor
#> 59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 60           5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#> 61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
#> 62           5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor
#> 63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
#> 64           6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 65           5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
#> 67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 68           5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor
#> 69           6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 70           5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor
#> 71           5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor
#> 72           6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#> 73           6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#> 74           6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor
#> 75           6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#> 76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor
#> 77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#> 78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor
#> 79           6.0         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
#> 81           5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
#> 82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
#> 83           5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor
#> 84           6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor
#> 85           5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 86           6.0         3.4          4.5         1.6 versicolor
#> 87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor
#> 88           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
#> 89           5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 versicolor
#> 90           5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#> 91           5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
#> 92           6.1         3.0          4.6         1.4 versicolor
#> 93           5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor
#> 94           5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor
#> 95           5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor
#> 96           5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor
#> 97           5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor
#> 98           6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#> 99           5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
#> 100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
#> 101        630.0         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
#> 102        580.0         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
#> 103        710.0         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
#> 104        630.0         2.9          5.6         1.8  virginica
#> 105        650.0         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
#> 106        760.0         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
#> 107        490.0         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica
#> 108        730.0         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
#> 109        670.0         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica
#> 110        720.0         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica
#> 111        650.0         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica
#> 112        640.0         2.7          5.3         1.9  virginica
#> 113        680.0         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica
#> 114        570.0         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica
#> 115        580.0         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica
#> 116        640.0         3.2          5.3         2.3  virginica
#> 117        650.0         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica
#> 118        770.0         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
#> 119        770.0         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
#> 120        600.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica
#> 121        690.0         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica
#> 122        560.0         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica
#> 123        770.0         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
#> 124        630.0         2.7          4.9         1.8  virginica
#> 125        670.0         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica
#> 126        720.0         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica
#> 127        620.0         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica
#> 128        610.0         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica
#> 129        640.0         2.8          5.6         2.1  virginica
#> 130        720.0         3.0          5.8         1.6  virginica
#> 131        740.0         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
#> 132        790.0         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
#> 133        640.0         2.8          5.6         2.2  virginica
#> 134        630.0         2.8          5.1         1.5  virginica
#> 135        610.0         2.6          5.6         1.4  virginica
#> 136        770.0         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
#> 137        630.0         3.4          5.6         2.4  virginica
#> 138        640.0         3.1          5.5         1.8  virginica
#> 139        600.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virginica
#> 140        690.0         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica
#> 141        670.0         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica
#> 142        690.0         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica
#> 143        580.0         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
#> 144        680.0         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica
#> 145        670.0         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica
#> 146        670.0         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica
#> 147        630.0         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica
#> 148        650.0         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica
#> 149        620.0         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica
#> 150        590.0         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica
#>                   Species2
#> 1      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 2      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 3      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 4      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 5      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 6      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 7      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 8      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 9      setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 10     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 11     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 12     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 13     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 14     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 15     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 16     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 17     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 18     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 19     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 20     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 21     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 22     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 23     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 24     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 25     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 26     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 27     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 28     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 29     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 30     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 31     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 32     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 33     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 34     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 35     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 36     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 37     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 38     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 39     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 40     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 41     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 42     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 43     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 44     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 45     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 46     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 47     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 48     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 49     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 50     setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 51              versicolor
#> 52              versicolor
#> 53              versicolor
#> 54              versicolor
#> 55              versicolor
#> 56              versicolor
#> 57              versicolor
#> 58              versicolor
#> 59              versicolor
#> 60              versicolor
#> 61              versicolor
#> 62              versicolor
#> 63              versicolor
#> 64              versicolor
#> 65              versicolor
#> 66              versicolor
#> 67              versicolor
#> 68              versicolor
#> 69              versicolor
#> 70              versicolor
#> 71              versicolor
#> 72              versicolor
#> 73              versicolor
#> 74              versicolor
#> 75              versicolor
#> 76              versicolor
#> 77              versicolor
#> 78              versicolor
#> 79              versicolor
#> 80              versicolor
#> 81              versicolor
#> 82              versicolor
#> 83              versicolor
#> 84              versicolor
#> 85              versicolor
#> 86              versicolor
#> 87              versicolor
#> 88              versicolor
#> 89              versicolor
#> 90              versicolor
#> 91              versicolor
#> 92              versicolor
#> 93              versicolor
#> 94              versicolor
#> 95              versicolor
#> 96              versicolor
#> 97              versicolor
#> 98              versicolor
#> 99              versicolor
#> 100             versicolor
#> 101 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 102 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 103 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 104 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 105 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 106 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 107 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 108 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 109 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 110 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 111 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 112 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 113 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 114 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 115 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 116 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 117 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 118 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 119 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 120 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 121 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 122 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 123 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 124 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 125 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 126 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 127 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 128 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 129 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 130 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 131 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 132 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 133 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 134 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 135 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 136 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 137 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 138 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 139 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 140 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 141 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 142 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 143 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 144 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 145 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 146 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 147 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 148 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 149 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
#> 150 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code with the `base` `replace` and the `dplyr` `if_else`-function. With `replace` the lengths should be the same. Hence, we need to subset the character vector with the logical expression as well.

For the multiplication dependent on the species, we need to use `if_else` because we do not "stay within our variable/column", but need information from other columns/variables (in this case Species).

```
library(dplyr)
data("iris")

iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

iris2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length = if_else(Species != "versicolor", Sepal.Length * 100, Sepal.Length),
         Species = replace(Species, Species!="versicolor",  
                           paste0(Species[ Species!="versicolor"], "_o0o0o0o0o0o0") ))
```

This yields:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width                Species
1          510         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
2            7         3.2          4.7         1.4             versicolor
3          630         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
```

Comment: It should not replace with `versicolor_oOooOOOoo` though, should it?

Answer (score 1):

here's a way that uses `magrittr::inset` instead of `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::if_else` :

```
iris %>% mutate_at("Species",as.character) %>%
 inset(x <- .$Species!="versicolor", c("Sepal.Length", "Species"),
       value = cbind(.$Sepal.Length[x] * 100, paste0(.$Species[x], "_o0o0o0o0o0o0"))) %>%
 distinct(Species, .keep_all = TRUE)

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width                Species
# 1          510         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa_o0o0o0o0o0o0
# 2            7         3.2          4.7         1.4             versicolor
# 3          630         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica_o0o0o0o0o0o0
```